# PHP Auto Delete an Array of Unwanted Files From All Folders on Server Script

Tags: php, automation

I have a couple of PHP scripts for deleting error_log, .DS_Store etc files from all folders on my entire server. I simply have these scripts uploaded to my root (public_html) and visit them periodically when I want to do a little cleanup. When I visit the URL of where the scripts are loaded it automatically gets to work. That's all perfect and how I'd like to continue using it.

However, I'd love to consolidate this automation into just one script where I can list an array of the undesirable files like so:

```
$unwanted_filenames = array(
'.DS_Store',
'.localized',
'Thumbs.db',
'error_log'
);
```

And simply run through all folders and delete all the files of which I've listed in the array.

The scripts I use now are overkill, listing out every individual file and how much it's freed up etc. I'm a minimalist and would love the simplest script with the least amount of code to just get the job done.

So when I visit the page it automatically get's to work, a white screen of nothing is fine and then maybe a simple "Done. Freed up 3MB." message. That's it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better not to upload stuff like that at the first place?!

Comment: Do you have access to shell ( exec() )? If so, run "rm" as it'll delete very quickly. Or set up a cron job to do the same?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I could exhaust an explanation of all the scenarios in which why undesirable files end up on the server, especially with error_log files, but I'll ask that you trust it's not as simple as just not uploading them to begin with.

Comment: @Robbie - Preference wise, I'm more interested in running a PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

OK - here's the shortest but of PHP I can think of that'll do it:

```
$unwanted_filenames = array(
    '.DS_Store',
    '.localized',
    'Thumbs.db',
    'error_log'
    );
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/");  // Set starting directory here
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
    if (in_array(basename($file), $unwanted_filenames)) {
        @unlink($file);  // THe @ hides errors, remove if you want to see them
    }
}
```

Hopefully self-explanatory - and yes, it does subdirectories (that's the "recursive" bit).

And you said minamalistic, so I didn't include the freed space, but just add a $FreedSpace += filesize($file) before the unlink if you want to add that in.

Comment: Beautifully simple. Only, I'm unable to get it to work. Dropped it in it's own PHP file adding `<?php ?>` and uploading to root, no go. I tried /public_html and the first folder name on my server just in case that made a difference, no go. Of course I understand that the screen will remain white and not appear to be doing anything so I've dropped a few example files in a sub-folder to see if they're deleted, no go. Is this working in your testing? If so, it's likely an Apache or permissions conflict on my server. Thanks

Comment: Yes, fully tested (unless a copy/paste error in the answer - but I can't see one). Turn on error reporting and remove the @ before unlink to find if there is error. Only issue is that it timed out after 30 seonds - so make sure you set timeout>30 seconds.

Comment: Changed error_reporting to 1, removed @ and even removed parts from .htaccess that might be effecting it, nothing. No errors, and page just results to done without the script executing anything. Please note I'm on Linux, a good host and I have all my PHP limits set to max. It's a head scratcher at the moment. If the script is working for you I'll have to tinker with the stuff going on, on my end. I'll report back if I get it figured out. I'll give you an upvote for now. Thanks.

Comment: Scratch that, got errors to display. I'm getting Fatal error: U in file.php on line 9. That line is `foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {`.

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: Scrub that - is hte error message "Fatal Error, uncaught exception"? In which case, wrap the call in a try/catch and echo the exception. That'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: My current version is 5.3.13. Should I request an update to 5.4.3? It reads exactly as `Fatal error: U in file.php on line 9`. "wrap the call in a try/catch and echo the exception" - That bit is definitely over my head. Also, unless you enjoy problem solving these kinds of issues (I do myself) I don't want to abuse your time. Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp and http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this, you can do it like this:

```
<?php    
    $dir = "/var/www/vhosts/"; //Write your dirname here
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));
    $total_thumbs = 0;
    $total_ds = 0;
    foreach ($rii as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()){
            continue;
        }

        $parcala = explode('.', $file->getFilename());
        $uzanti = end($parcala);

        if ($file->getFilename() == 'Thumbs.db') {
            unlink($file->getPathname());
            $total_thumbs++;
        }

        if ($uzanti == '.DS_Store' || $file->getFilename() == 'DS_Store' || $file->getFilename() == '.DS_Store') {
            unlink($file->getPathname());
            $total_ds++;
        }
    }

    echo $total_thumbs . ' Thumbs.db file and ' . $total_ds . ' DS_Store file deleted!';
```

And if you want automation you can use **Cronjob**